# How do I call a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript code in a file named cookies.js

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) 
{
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

My html file looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cookies.js">
    //how to call the function 
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

how can i call setCookie function with parameters.

Comment: You include the file, then add another script tag and call `setCookie` as you normally would.

Comment: The source of Your code is in there: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming cookies.js puts the function on the global scope, you can just create a second script tag and reference setCookie.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cookies.js"></script>
<script> 
    setCookie('hello', 'world', 0);
</script>
```